# Permutation optimization problem

Tags: optimization, permutations

Here is the problem as posed by Jerrum:

"The computational complexity of the following problem is investigated: Given a permutation group specified as a set of generators, and a single target permutation which is a member 
of the group, what is the shortest expression for the target permutation in terms of the generators?"

Jerrum, Mark R. "[The complexity of finding minimum-length generator sequences.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397585900477)" Theoretical Computer Science 36 (1985): 265-289.

What is the current state of the art algorithm for finding min-length generator sequences over small ( n<13 ) permutations?

The simple approach seems to be caching prefixes and growing them when a length $i+1$ word (composed into a permutation) is not contained in any of the length $1..i$ words. You either reach the target permutation, or at some length your words no longer compose into new permutations so you know the target is unreachable.

Comment: Also, the weighted version of this problem where each generator has an associated cost would be nice for the particular application I have in mind.